# Themes and backgrounds aren't showing up

Tags: windows-7, windows

i am running Windows 7 64 bit.  My themes and background pictures are not showing up when i try to change them.  but when i go to log off my computer i see the theme or background pic for a split second as it shuts off.  Help please

Comment: Are you logged into a domain?

Comment: I've only heard of this behaviour when there is a virus on the computer, or Microsoft has deemed your Windows installation as "not genuine".

Answer (score 0):

As per I have seen you will see that screen when you may not using genuine version. It will appear as a black screen. And at the right side bottom the message of  not genuine version.

to sort out the perfect problem put here a image of it so i can find out further solution for that.

Hope it will help you.